# position: sticky not working if parent has overflow:auto style

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a container that contains a sidebar and a content wrapper. I need to set `overflow` of container to `auto`, but the sidebar `sticky` position don't work when it's parent has the `overflow:auto` style!

Comment: Ah, best to show all of your code as otherwise it will cause confusion to those trying to help

Comment: you need to remove overflow, it's the only solution or use JS to simulate a sticky behavior